# How to get any type posts include attachments by ids?

Tags: query-posts, attachments

I need to get any posts by an id list ($id_list), here is my codes

```
query_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>-1,
               'caller_get_posts'=>1,
               'post_type'=>'any',
               'post__in'=>$id_list)
           );
```

i got posts and pages by this query, but attachments don't get included, i found they are filtered by 'post_type=any' which actually doesn't include attachment.

How do i get them all without have to do an extra query?

Comment: Attachments don't have a `publish` status, which is default for the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'post_type'=>'any' should get you all types except revisions so you should get the attachments but if you don't try:

```
query_posts( array( 
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'ignore_stickies' => 1,
               'post_type'=> array( 'post', 'page', 'attachment' ),
               'post_status' => array( null ),
               'post__in'=> $id_list 
) );
```

### Update

As  t31os pointed out that:

> Attachments don't have a publish
>   status, which is default for the query

so i added to the query_posts array `'post_status' => null` and that should fix your query

Comment: still no luck, i guess it is a bug

Comment: See my comment on your question.

Comment: @t31os @Edward , updated the code in the answer

Comment: @t31os @Bainternet, you are rock! All about 'post_status' and i can get all expected results now. Just a small issue, code should be 'post_status' => array(null), "null" is treated not set and wordpress will use the default value instead.

Comment: **Note:** `'post_status' => null` cannot work since WP_Query checks this using `empty()` and reverts to defaults. But `'post_status' => array(null)` might work depending on the SQL it creates, though it's a bit hackish.